# TweetSharp c# reply Tweeter

Tags: c#

НЕ могу понять как сделать ответ на твит , который нашел по поиску. 
Суть такая по иску ищу ключевое слово и хочу сделать ответ на него ... уже все функции перебрал , отвечаю только сам себе и все тут .. Кто работал именно с TWEETSHARP как сделать ответ на твит!?

```
   private void readnews (string text,int maxcount)
    {
        string consumerKey = "xxxxxx";
        string consumerSecret = "xxxxxxx";
        string Access_Token = "xxxxxxxx";
        string Access_Token_Secret = "xxxxxxxxx";
        string message = textBox2.Text.Trim();
        try
        {
            var service = new TwitterService(consumerKey, consumerSecret);

            service.AuthenticateWith(Access_Token, Access_Token_Secret);
            var options = new SearchOptions { Q = text, Count = maxcount, Resulttype = TwitterSearchResultType.Mixed };

            var tweets = service.Search(options);
            foreach (var tweet in tweets.Statuses)
            {

                string listmessages = string.Format("{0} ответил '{1}'", tweet.User.ScreenName, tweet.Text);

                service.SendTweet(new SendTweetOptions { PlaceId = tweet.Id, TrimUser = true, Status = message });
                listBox1.Items.Add(listmessages);
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }


   private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Clear();

        readnews(textBox1.Text, Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   private void readnews(string text, int maxcount)
{
    Random r = new Random();

    string message = words[r.Next(0, words.Length)];

    try
    {

        var options = new SearchOptions { Q = text, Count = maxcount, Resulttype = TwitterSearchResultType.Mixed };
        var tweets = service.Search(options);


        foreach (var tweet in tweets.Statuses)
        {

            string listmessages = string.Format("{0} ответил '{1}'", tweet.User.ScreenName, tweet.Text);
            if (tweet.RetweetedStatus == null)
            {
                label5.Text = i++.ToString();
                listBox1.Items.Add(listmessages);
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                service.SendTweet(new SendTweetOptions { Status = "@" + tweet.User.ScreenName + " " + message, InReplyToStatusId = tweet.Id });

            }
            else { }
        }
    }
}
```